# Ignore max_srcset_image_width filter for one particular image

Tags: wordpress, responsive-images, srcset

I've limited the image sizes output by `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` to 768 pixels (by default they are limited to 1600 pixels):

```
function set_max_srcset_image_width( $max_srcset_image_width, $sizes_array ) {
    return 768;
}
add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'set_max_srcset_image_width', 10, 2 );
```

However, I have one image where I would like to revert back to the default of 1600 max.

Since the `max_srcset_image_width` filter doesn't include any additional arguments to identify an image or the fact that you might want to override the max size, I can't figure out how to do this.  At the moment it means either all of my images include too big a size, or one of my images is too small.

Comment: What would be criteria of the original image to which you want to revert to 1600? `$sizes_array[0]` contains the original image width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this as follows:

```
// Limit srcset images to 768 pixels
function set_max_srcset_image_width( $max_srcset_image_width, $sizes_array ) {
    return 768;
}
add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'set_max_srcset_image_width', 10, 2 );
```

Then when I have an image where I want to include the 1,600 version and ignore the 768 maximum, I did this:

```
<img srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'large' ); ?>" />
```

Where `large` is the 1600 pixel version.

I could never figure out what the second parameter in `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` was for because it never seemed to restrict the function to outputting a maximum or minimum size.  However in the example here it does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

See contribution by @Joe McGill [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/max_srcset_image_width/)

```
 function custom_max_srcset_image_width( $max_width, $size_array ) {

      $width = $size_array[0];

      if ( $width <= 640 ) { //Aribitrary - Change to meet your needs
        $max_width = 1600;
        return $max_width;
      }else{
        return 768;
     }

  add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'custom_max_srcset_image_width', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks, although I'm confused about how this will work.  Let's say all of my images are available at 768 and 1600 pixels.  I want the maximum size in the `srcset` to be 768.  But there is one image somewhere where I want the maximum size to be 1600 pixels.  I can't see how the above helps since it doesn't know which image is which.

Comment: It's  sounding more and more like you need to simply style your images for display. See: [link] https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Images_in_Posts_and_Pages  . See section **Styling All Images** and **Styling Specific Images**

Comment: There is also this: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702900/maximum-image-width-for-a-wordpress-theme-or-any-theme-really?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your help, I seemed to resolve the issue and have posted my own answer